# Selective replacement of unicode characters in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode

There are many answers as to how one can use regex to remove unicode characters in Python.

See [Remove Unicode code (\uxxx) in string Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010727/remove-unicode-code-uxxx-in-string-python) and [Python regex module "re" match unicode characters with \u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377962/python-regex-module-re-match-unicode-characters-with-u)

However, in my case, I don't want to replace every unicode character but only the ones that are displayed with their \u code, not the ones that are properly shown as characters. I have tried both solutions and they remove both types of unicode characters.

`\u2002pandemic` becomes `pandemic`
and `master’s` becomes `masters`

Is there a general solutions to removing the first type of unicode characters but keeping the second kind?

Comment: What do you have against those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the idea that the debug representation (`repr()`) of a text will show escape codes for non-printable characters, so it removes those escape codes (three types: \xnn, \unnnn, \Unnnnnnnn) and evaluates the result:

```py
import re
import ast

text = '\x19\x40\u2002\u2019\U0001e526\U0001f235\\u1234\\U00012345\\xff\\\u2002'
#       ^^^^    ^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^
# To remove above, others are printable escape codes or literal backslashes.
# If preceded by an odd number of backslashes, it's an escape code.
print('printed text:   ', text)
print('repr() text:    ', repr(text))
clean_text = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'''(?x)                # verbose mode
                                         (?<!\\)             # not preceded by literal backslash
                                         ((?:\\\\)*)         # zero or more pairs literal backslashes (group 1)
                                         \\                  # match a literal backslash
                                         (?:                 # non-capturing group
                                         (?:x[0-9a-f]{2}) |  # match an x and 2 hexadecimal digits OR
                                         (?:u[0-9a-f]{4}) |  # match a u and 4 hex digits OR
                                         (?:U[0-9a-f]{8})    # match a U and 8 hex digits
                                         )                   # end non-capturing group
                                         ''',
                                         r'\1'               # replace with group 1 (pairs of backslashes, if any)
                                         , repr(text)))      # string to operate on
print('cleaned text:   ', clean_text)
print('cleaned repr(): ', repr(clean_text))
```

Output:

```
printed text:    @ ’\u1234\U00012345\xff\ 
repr() text:     '\x19@\u2002’\U0001e526\\u1234\\U00012345\\xff\\\u2002'
cleaned text:    @’\u1234\U00012345\xff\
cleaned repr():  '@’\\u1234\\U00012345\\xff\\'
```

Note you may not want to remove *all* characters that display as escape codes.  Their `str()` (print display) vs. `repr()` (debug display) may be something desirable.  For example, `\u2002` is an `EN SPACE` (another type of SPACE character) and prints as a space.  The debug representation only shows it as an escape code so you can tell the difference between an ASCII `SPACE` and an `EN SPACE`.

Comment: This works for me however it does add double quotes around strings, should I simply remove them after?

Comment: @user1627466 printing with `repr()` adds the quotes.  See `cleaned text: ` line.

Comment: @KellyBundy Fixed.  Any more? Getting complicated :)

Comment: Might be correct now :-). I think instead of the `(?<!\\)`, you could instead put `|` between the backslash-pairs and the rest.

Comment: And then you could just match single pairs, with `(\\\\)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's [`isprintable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isprintable#str.isprintable) exactly for this type of thing:

```
src = 'a \u200d \x1f Ü ß ы'

cleaned = ''.join(c for c in src if c.isprintable())

print(repr(src))
print(repr(cleaned))

# 'a \u200d \x1f Ü ß ы'
# 'a   Ü ß ы'
```

Comment: Or `cleaned = ''.join(filter(str.isprintable, src))`.